# Stop or Crash my browser when i load data from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hy guys
I have the following code in my JS file

```
 function load(){
   $.ajax({
         url: "http://blah-blah.com/file.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {data:"blah"},
         typeData: "json",
         success: function(data){
          $("#divLoad").html(data);
          load();
         }     
   });
var reload = setInterval({"load()"}, 5000);
// or can use this
var reload = setTimeout({"load()"}, 5000);
}
```

and the following in file.php

```
 point to --> echo json_encode('<div id="a">$r[name]</div><div id="b">$r[sex]</div>');
```

Why does executing the above code hang my browser / computer, and shows a very high CPU usage?

Comment: Maybe because you call `load();` again from `success` function

Comment: @j809 imagine how many threads this infinitely called load will produce

Comment: thank very much.. I mistake, 
but why for var reload = setInterval({"load()"}, 5000);
// or can use this
var reload = setTimeout({"load()"}, 5000);
not work..

Answer (score 2):

Because `load` is a recursive function, it calls itself in the `success` callback.

By calling it periodically with `setInterval`, you will progressively build up more and more ajax calls.

Remove the recursive `load()` call in the `success` function and you are good to go:

```
function load(){
   $.ajax({
         url: "http://blah-blah.com/file.php",
         type: "POST",
         data: {data:"blah"},
         typeData: "json",
         success: function(data){
          $("#divLoad").html(data);
          //load(); <--remove this
         }     
   });
}
```

Comment: but for this not work

var reload = setInterval({"load()"}, 5000);
// or can use this
var reload = setTimeout({"load()"}, 5000);

Comment: @Whendy you can set `setTimeout` in `$.ajax` `.always()` callback

Comment: @Regent, I just started to learn about this, so can I see an example? pleace. I was confused to put it, thnk u